# How to transform this file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, data-science, data-analysis

Hello I have this file :

```
a|b|c|d|
1.05 january february 05-02-2010 Linux Mint
3.458 november december 05-02-2010 Windows 10
```

And I would like using pandas with Python transform this file in csv like this :

```
a;b;c;d
1.05;january february;05-02-2010;Linux Mint
3.458;november december;05-02-2010;Windows 10
```

I have no really idea to do this... could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: So, your starting point is what indicates a pipe delimited file, followed by space delimiter rows with no escaping to indicate that "january february" should be one column and not two? pandas isn't going to help you here... you've got to work out some logic of how to identify those columns or fix your input file.

Comment: Do you know the structure of content in this file? For example,  "c" column always date-like string.

Comment: df.to_csv(fname, separator=‘;’), read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: You might have to do line parsing to find the date, format, then based on the knowledge of having a single column in front, join everything after that until the date as one column, then take everything after the date as another column... but whether that'll work for you or scale... *shrugs*... not a pandas problem though.

Comment: @Ken you're assuming you can get the input into a format where that'll work - it doesn't look to be the case here.

Comment: @JonClements we can skip the header line and read the rest of the data and define the header line later on.

Comment: @Ken sure... but pandas is going to throw errors unless there's the same amount of columns... what if the first one is Linux Mint 9? Then another line on the input is "january february march"... you've got a large amount of data munging to do on the line level even before you try to present it to a DF.

Comment: Peter - are you sure your first line is definitely space separated and not actually: `1.05|january february|05-02-2010|Linux Mint` ?

Comment: I think if we define delimiter when reading the file, it is going to be fine, i.e., `sep=';`'. Just skip the header part and define the header later on

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [212]: df = pd.read_csv('ff.txt', skiprows=1, header=None, sep=' ')
In [211]: df
Out[211]: 
       0         1         2           3        4     5
0  1.050   january  february  05-02-2010    Linux  Mint
1  3.458  november  december  05-02-2010  Windows    10

In [232]: df['months'] = df[1].map(str) +' '+ df[2]

In [233]: df['end_cols'] = df[4].map(str) +' '+ df[5]

In [237]: df.drop([1,2,4,5], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [238]: df = df[[0,'months',3,'end_cols']]

In [239]: df
Out[239]: 
       0             months           3    end_cols
0  1.050   january february  05-02-2010  Linux Mint
1  3.458  november december  05-02-2010  Windows 10

#Now, extract header from original file
In [216]: with open('ff.txt', 'r') as f:
     ...:     header = f.readline()

In [217]: header
Out[217]: 'a|b|c|d\n'

In [245]: df.columns = header.strip().split('|')

# write the data to the file with delimiter =';'
In [224]: df.to_csv('abc.csv', sep=';', index=False)

#Final Output

mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat abc.csv 
a;b;c;d
1.05;january february;05-02-2010;Linux Mint
3.458;november december;05-02-2010;Windows 10
```

Comment: @PeterH Please let me know if the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you mean transforming in-memory, or writing back to file.

If it's latter you might be looking for

`df.to_csv(out_df='filename', sep=';')`

- in combination with some column-label manipulation as mentioned in the other answer